# Using PHP to output XML

Tags: php, xml

```
<?
    $MySQLPassword = "indian";  
    $HostName = "localhost";    
    $UserName = "monty";

    mysql_connect($HostName,$UserName,$MySQLPassword)
    or die("ERROR: Could not connect to database!");

    mysql_select_db("sachin") or die("cannot select db");

    $keyword = $_POST['keyword'];
    echo $keyword;
   /* Execute the query that performs the actual search in the DB: */
   $result = mysql_query(" SELECT p.page_url AS url,
                           COUNT(*) AS occurrences 
                           FROM page p, word w, occurrence o
                           WHERE p.page_id = o.page_id AND
                           w.word_id = o.word_id AND
                           w.word_word = \"$keyword\"
                           GROUP BY p.page_id
                           ORDER BY occurrences DESC
                           " );

$output = new DOMDocument();
$output->formatOutput = true;
$output = "<loginsuccess>";

for( $i = 1; $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $i++ )      {


$output .="<person><keyword>".$_POST['keyword']."</keyword><name>".$row['url']."</name><occur>".$row['occurrences']."</occur></person>";
}

$output .= "</loginsuccess>";
print ($output);

?>
```

I am getting the output as XML, but i need to store it in a separate xml file, can any one help me out.

One more question,....

I am using fwrite and able to write into a file, but how can i clear the file each time it writes, instead of writing at the end of file? i need the existing content to be destroyed and re written again.

Comment: Note that you might get trouble by outputting raw data from the DB to XML without escaping special characters. Particularly the URL where you can have & chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [fwrite](https://www.php.net/fwrite).

EDIT: To truncate, use:

```
$handle = fopen($filename , "wb")
```

when doing the open.
The w means open for writing and truncate to 0 length.  The b means binary mode so Windows doesn't mess with your line endings.

Comment: addition: you can use xml_encode() to save some lines in your code.

Answer (score 2):

file_put_contents is the easiest way of dumping a string to file.

Answer (score 0):

Just the simple file functions, check them out over at the PHP.net website.

Answer (score -2):

In addition, you wanna make sure your properly escape the contents of the XML file. [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/htmlentities) is a good place to start reading up on the subject, or you can just use `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>`